# Trying to plot a parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Trying to plot the curve $x=t, y=\sqrt(1-t^2)$ on [-1,1],

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle,xtick={2},ytick={2},
no marks,axis equal,xmin=-1.4,xmax=1.2,ymax=1.2,ymin=-0.2,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
          \addplot[no markers,samples=100, domain=-1:1,variable=t]({t},{sqrt(1-(t)^2)});
        \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get a PGF Math error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point...

Where do I wrong ?

Later Edit: I've written the full code, according to @Cragfelt 's comment.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's `sqrt(1-(t)^2)` and not `\sqrt{1-t^{2}}`.

Comment: If you don't mind cheating a little, this plot is actually the upper half of the unit circle… It's much easier to draw it as such :-)

Comment: Indeed, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle,xtick={2},ytick={2},
no marks,axis equal,xmin=-1.4,xmax=1.2,ymax=1.2,ymin=-0.2,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
           \addplot[no markers,samples=100,
           domain=-1:1,variable=t]({t},{pow(1-t^2,1/2)});
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `pow(1-t^2,1/2)` and not `sqrt(1-(t)^2)`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Both work, but not `\sqrt{1-t^2}`. Sorry, after I uploaded this answer, I saw your comment. I'll be happy to delete the answer if you ask me to.